# Tabula-py - ImportError: No module named tabula

Tags: python, tabula

I am trying to use Tabula-py to read a pdf. I installed tabula-py through `pip install tabula-py`

I have also installed the required dependencies

```
requests
pandas
pytest
flake8
```

My code is currently as follows:

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd

df = tabula.read_pdf("report.pdf", pages=2)
print(df)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tabula_pdf_reader.py", line 1, in <module>
  import tabula
ImportError: No module named tabula
```

Any inputs to what I am missing here?

Comment: Looks like your install of tabula failed. You are getting a failure on the `import` statement. That means the interpreter disagrees with your view that you have installed it.

Comment: `pip install tabula-py` gives `Requirement already satisfied: tabula-py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, so I assume that it is correctly installed?

Comment: Do you maybe have more than one Python environment? The only thing I can think of that would cause what you describe is if you installed tabula in 2.7 but are importing it in a 3.6 interpreter session.

Comment: I do have 2 python environments. But I am running it through terminal which is using 2.7. I verified this by `which python` which gave `/usr/bin/python` and then I checked the version `/usr/bin/python -version` which gave 2.7

Comment: Well I installed tabula-py for python3 and ran it with python3 and it worked. Looks like some python2 specific issue on my end.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this same issue in Ubuntu.

First, check the version of the JDK and JRE that are installed on your machine by running `java --version` and `javac --version`. Each should have a version greater than 7.

Then use `pip3` to install tabula.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue here when executing on Terminal. 
However, after I ran by starting with 'ipython3' instead of 'ipython', it worked perfectly.
You have to make sure that tabula-py module is installed in python3 directory, not python2

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 import camelot
 tables = camelot.read_pdf('foo.pdf')
 tables.export('foo.csv', f='csv', compress=True)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS users - an update to Monterey operating system will solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Azure ML studio. I solved the issue by changing the python interpreter to Python 3.8 - AzureML (might be different for you, try different ones or maybe the interpreter can be deducted from the path below). Then include the path to the installed packages with:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
```

Change the path to whatever you get when you run:

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print(get_python_lib())
```

hopefully it helps someone :)