# tabula-py ImportError: cannot import name 'read_pdf'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pdf, tabula

Im trying to use tabula-py to transfer a table from pdf to excel.

When im trying to

```
from tabula import read_pdf
```

it says

ImportError: cannot import name 'read_pdf'

All solutions i found say that i have to

```
pip uninstall tabula
pip3 install tabula-py
```

https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/issues/47

[Tabula-py - ImportError: No module named tabula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596477/tabula-py-importerror-no-module-named-tabula)

But its still not working for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: instead if `import tabula from read_pdf`, do `from tabula import read_pdf`

Comment: @Flika205 sorry, that was just a spelling mistake. my code is 'from tabula import read_pdf' - changed it in OP

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this is because of the version of tabula you installed.

If you installed tabula by running:

```
pip install tabula
```

You get an old version of tabula (1.0.5) that has the problem with the module .read_pdf().
To fix the problem and get a newer version of tabula, first:

uninstall tabula with the command:

```
pip uninstall tabula
```

And install the newer version of tabula with the command:

```
pip install tabula-py
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: It also solved my problem. However, the important thing was that I had to close CMD, and open again, and run a fresh jupyter notebook (simply restarting jupyter notebook did not work).

Comment: This did not immediately solve my problem because, I think, I had both `tabula` and `tabula-py` install. I had to uninstall both then  reinstall `tabula-py` by itself to get it to work.

Answer (score 6):

```
from tabula import wrapper
df = wrapper.read_pdf('my_pdf')
```

read_pdf is contained within 'wrapper'. Hence you import wrapper and call read_pdf from wrapper.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Comment: I believe the issue arises becuase of tabula updating the method. Now the method read_pdf sits inside of wrapper.

Comment: nope, it doesn't solve the problem, an error comes up :
_cannot import name 'wrapper' from 'tabula' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tabula/__init__.py)_

Comment: It doesn't work.
ImportError: cannot import name 'wrapper' from 'tabula' (/tmp/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tabula/__init__.py)

Answer (score 4):

I solved as follows:

1. upgrade pip to pi3: pip install --upgrade pip --user

pip3 uninstall tabula-py

pip3 install tabula-py

That solved the problem perfectly!
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is a chance that you're testing tabula-py within a module you named **tabula.py**

This would throw the same exact error because of [module import order in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#namespace-packages)

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I have installed it with `pip install tabula-py`

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I had this same problem. The file I was using to write the code was named 'tabula.py'. I wrote the code in a new file, with a new name, and had to delete the file named 'tabula.py'.

Once I did that the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

```
Step 1:- Upgrade PIP
 python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip --u

Step2 : make sure its upgraded in your virtual environment
(venv) D:\dMig\venv\Lib\site-packages>pip install --upgrade pip --user
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in d:\python38\lib\site-packages (20.2)

Step3: Uninstall earlier version 
(venv) D:\dMig\venv\Lib\site-packages>pip3 uninstall tabula-py

Step4: Install again
pip3 install tabula-py

Step5: Verify by below code

from tabula import read_pdf

#declare the path of your file
file_path = "E:\Activity.pdf"

#Convert your file
df = read_pdf(file_path)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution -
1- uninstall the old tabula

```
pip uninstall tabula
```

2- install the new tabula-py

```
pip install tabula-py
```

then use the module

```
from tabula import read_pdf
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
from tabula.io import read_pdf
df = read_pdf('file.pdf', pages='all')
```